# Storing multiple ID's in localStorage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am wanting to add a favorites function for my website. The technologies I am using are html, css, javascript and json. I am loading the json file thru ajax. A user is able to search for a device and add that device to their favourites and that is done via sessionStorage and localStorage, but my problem is when a user clicks on a new phone to add to their favorite, it overrides it. Do I have to put like an IF statement which will say if there is an id there still add this one. I am confused on how to do this...

Code Samples....

```
$(document).on('click', '.productfavourite', function(event) { 

  // whichever HTML element has been clicked,
  // grab the id of that and set it as product fave
  productFave = event.target.id;

  localStorage.setItem('productFave', productFave);
  console.log(productFave);
  window.location="favourites.html";
});
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('productFave', productFave);` You set a value of the item `productFave`, obviously overwriting what is in there. What would you expect? That setItem would actually get the item, parse it, add an extra value to it and store it back? That's something you need to build yourself. Maybe there is a getItem?...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you save the selected items in an object or array before you write it in to the localStorage. After that you convert the object or array to a json string.

```
var selected = [];
$(document).on('click', '.productfavourite', function(event) {
    selected.push(event.target.id);
    console.log(selected);
});
```

this returns an array that your can convert to json.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is to keep a collection (list or dictionary) containing the favorites. I'll give you some examples, then you can figure out the rest.

You get the current `productFav` in your localStorage as follows:

```
var fav = localStorage.getItem("productFav") || [];
```

Now you don't want to store one value in localStorage, you want your whole list there. So you add the new favorites to the list and serialize the result as a json string

```
fav.push(newItem);

localstorage.setitem("productfav", JSON.stringify(fav));
```

I assumed `fav` is a list. It's best to use a dictionary if you want to avoid adding duplicated entries

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
if(Storage !== "undefined") {
   localStorage.setItem("productFave", localStorage.getItem("productFave")+ ", newItemValue3");
}
```